# Create binary matrix files after getting count data from a list

Tags: r

In a directory, I have many text files, name and format of the files are as follows:

```
SRS011061.txt
--------------------
contig SRS011061_idxstats.txt
BGC0000505 1
BGC0000505 1

SRS011090.txt
---------------------
contig SRS011090_idxstats.txt
BGC0000509 0
BGC0000509 1

SRS011271.txt
--------------------
contig SRS011271_idxstats.txt
BGC00001105 0
BGC00001105 0
```

From these files, I want two types of results:

1. In each file, how many genes (BGC**) are present when we consider different percentage of gene presence (1/0 is presence and absence).

For this step, I use:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/test")
filenames <- list.files(full.names=F, pattern=".txt")
output <-lapply(filenames,function(i){
  t<-read.csv(i, header=T, check.names = F, sep = " ")
  t$gene_count<-1
  t[,2][t[,2]>0]<-1
  pre_abs<-aggregate(. ~ contig, t, sum)
  colnames(pre_abs)<-c("BGC_Accession","Gene_presence", "Gene_count")
  pre_abs$Percentage<-(pre_abs$Gene_presence/pre_abs$Gene_count)*100
  gene_pre_100_percent<-length(pre_abs$Percentage[pre_abs$Percentage>=100])
  gene_pre_20_percent<-length(pre_abs$Percentage[pre_abs$Percentage>=20])
  data.frame(Combinations=i,gene_pre_100_percent=gene_pre_100_percent,gene_pre_20_percent=gene_pre_20_percent)
})
Step2_TP_FP<-do.call(rbind,output)
Step2_TP_FP[,1] <- data.frame(gsub(".txt.*$", "", Step2_TP_FP[,1]))
```

Here I get the results that at 100% and 20% gene completion, how many numbers of genes are present at each file.

```
Combinations gene_pre_100_percent gene_pre_20_percent
SRS011061 1 1
SRS011090 0 1
SRS011271 0 0
```

2. For the same percentage criteria, I want to make a binary presence absence matrix. For 100% criteria, the matrix should look like:

```
SRS011061 SRS011090 SRS011271
BGC0000505 1 0 0
BGC0000509 0 0 0
BGC00001105 0 0 0
```

And for 20% criteria, it should be:

```
SRS011061 SRS011090 SRS011271
BGC0000505 1 0 0
BGC0000509 0 1 0
BGC00001105 0 0 0
```

How to create these two matrix files after getting the step1 results?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can print the gene names in the output table as follows:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/test")
filenames <- list.files(full.names=F, pattern=".txt")
output <-lapply(filenames,function(i){
  t<-read.csv(i, header=T, check.names = F, sep = " ")
  t$gene_count<-1
  t[,2][t[,2]>0]<-1
  pre_abs<-aggregate(. ~ contig, t, sum)
  colnames(pre_abs)<-c("BGC_Accession","Gene_presence", "Gene_count")
  pre_abs$Percentage<-(pre_abs$Gene_presence/pre_abs$Gene_count)*100
  gene_pre_100_percent<-length(pre_abs$Percentage[pre_abs$Percentage>=100])
  gene_pre_20_percent<-length(pre_abs$Percentage[pre_abs$Percentage>=20])
  bgc_name <- unique(pre_abs$BGC_Accession)
  data.frame(Combinations=i,gene_pre_100_percent=gene_pre_100_percent,gene_pre_20_percent=gene_pre_20_percent, bgc_name=bgc_name)
})
Step2_TP_FP<-do.call(rbind,output)
Step2_TP_FP[,1] <- data.frame(gsub(".txt.*$", "", Step2_TP_FP[,1]))
```

It gives me:

```
Combinations    gene_pre_100_percent    gene_pre_20_percent bgc_name
SRS011061   1   1   BGC0000505
SRS011090   0   1   BGC0000509
SRS011271   0   0   BGC00001105
```

Now I need to find a way to reshape this matrix to the above mentioned structure. For that, I will post another question if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier if you keep all the information and store the presence as a percentage, instead of hard coding the 20 or 80%, and then make the matrix at one shot. For example for one file, we can do:

```
output = lapply(fl,function(i){
   x = read.table(i,header=TRUE)
   cbind(aggregate(x[,2],list(gene=x[,1]),mean),
         file=sub(".txt","",i)
         )
})

output = do.call(rbind,output)

         gene   x      file
1  BGC0000505 1.0 SRS011061
2  BGC0000509 0.5 SRS011090
3 BGC00001105 0.0 SRS011271
```

Now it's just a matter of setting the cutoff for getting the matrix, and you change it to 50%,60% whatever, without reading the file in again:

```
matrixfunc = function(da,perc){
  table(da$gene[da$x>perc],da$file[da$x>perc])
}

matrixfunc(output,0.8)
             
              SRS011061 SRS011090 SRS011271
  BGC0000505          1         0         0
  BGC0000509          0         0         0
  BGC00001105         0         0         0

matrixfunc(output,0.2)
             
              SRS011061 SRS011090 SRS011271
  BGC0000505          1         0         0
  BGC0000509          0         1         0
  BGC00001105         0         0         0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I would like to keep the structure of the script same. After your answer, I found that I can print name of genes in my code. I am explaining this below